# AngularJS only shows last Element in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, flexslider

I've got a strange behaviour using flexslider to render a bunch of galleries. As shown below I've got an array of several objects that conclude an array of images. When I "render" the galleries, all galleries appear but only the last one shows its images. On all galleries the indicator for the number of images in that particular, as well as the title and link, are correct, but the images are missing.

Do I do something(/a lot) wrong here?
Here is my code:

```
$scope.galleries = [{title: 'gallery1', 'link': 'http://...', elements: 
                        ['img/img1.jpg','img/img2.jpg']},
                    {title: 'gallery2', 'link': 'http://...', elements: 
                        ['img/img3.jpg','img/img4.jpg']}];
```

I want to show each gallery with a directive and ng-repeat. The directive should show the title and render the gallery with flexslider(https://github.com/thenikso/angular-flexslider). Directive:

```
.directive('gallery', function() {
      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          templateUrl: 'views/gallery.html',
          scope: {
              gallery: '='
          },
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              // first generate html, the

              // set content here
              scope.link = scope.gallery.link;
              scope.title = scope.gallery.title;
              scope.elements = angular.copy(scope.gallery.elements);
              scope.num = scope.gallery.elements.length;

          }
      };
  }
```

Here the template:

```
<a ng-href="{{link}}" target="_blank" ng-bind="title"></a>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="flexslider">
    <div class="slides-control">
    <a href="" ng-click="prevSlideshow()" class="prev">
    <
      </a>
      <span class="current_pos">1</span>
      /
      <span ng-bind="num" class="total"></span>
        <a href="" ng-click="nextSlideshow()" class="next">
        >
      </a>
    </div>

        <ul ng-click="nextSlideshow()" class="slides" slideshow="false" control-nav="false" direction-nav="false" flex-slider slide="element in elements">
            <li><img ng-src="{{element}}" alt=""></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
  <a ng-href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><h4>more</h4></a>
<h5>---------------------------------------</h5>
</div>
```

And finally how i call it:

```
<ul class="publications" >
    <li ng-repeat="gallery in galleries">
        <div gallery="gallery"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle or plnkr to illustrate the issue? Also, are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Hey, No errors in console. Fiddle gonna be there later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I've got some **good news** and some **bad news**...

**Good News** You are doing nothing wrong in your code

**Bad News** You are doing nothing wrong in your code

**Explanation**
The directive you're trying to use `FlexSlider` has some limitations as currently written. The reason you're only seeing one set of data rendered is because the association of the slide attribute and all other logic within the directive is written into the `compile` (*see line 11 in flex-slider.js*) function when  anything related to the `scope` of the directive should be performed within the `link` function.

**Options**

1. Contact the developer of the directive and submit a bug report
2. Resolve the issue yourself within the directive
3. Write your own component

**[Here is a plnkr I created](http://plnkr.co/edit/9nU34VX74bYpezK6x7Um?p=preview)**
This plnkr shows an ng-repeat that I added to illustrate that you're code *should* be working based upon how the directive was created.

**Note** The developer likely never came across this scenario as the intention for creating it may have been to only have one instance at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for bringing up this problem and analyze it! 
It was indeed an `angular-flexslider`'s directive issue.
It has been addressed in http://github.com/thenikso/angular-flexslider/issues/20

Comment: Awesome! I love when developers are on top of their code and comments surrounding them, thanks for making the fix.

Answer (score -1):

General information for users who begin with AngularJs :

Some times you use dropdown with `ng-repeat`

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Language</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-repeat="language in languages">
    <li>
        <a href="#">{{ language.name | translate }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Don't forget that ng-repeat will repeat the ul too. The output is :

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Language</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu ng-scope" role="menu" ng-repeat="language in languages">
        <li><a href="#" ng-click="changeLanguage(language.abv)" class="ng-binding">French</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu ng-scope" role="menu" ng-repeat="language in languages">
        <li><a href="#" ng-click="changeLanguage(language.abv)" class="ng-binding">English</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

We can see two `ul` with a dropdown, this is bad, this is why you can see only last element of the arrays.
This is the correct way :

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Language</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="language in languages">
        <a href="#">{{ language.name | translate }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Hope it help !