# Angular JS Flex Slider

Tags: angularjs, flexslider, angularjs-ng-repeat

Really new to angular js im a couple of days in. I want to create a slider using flexslider and build the slider and use image from my data that I pull. I know you have to create a directive or something. If some could put me in the right direction that would be great.. I know the mark up has to go something like this but not sure how to create the flexslider..

thanks

```
angular.module("sportsStore")
.directive("slider", function ($timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {
            items: "="
        },
            templateUrl: "AngularJS/views/sliderTemplate.html",
            compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
                return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    $timeout((function() {
                return element.flexslider();
            }), 0);

        }
        }
    }
})
.controller("homeCtrl", function ($scope) {
$scope.arr = ["http://placehold.it/150&text=1",
    "http://placehold.it/150&text=2",
    "http://placehold.it/150&text=3"]
```

})

```
template 

   <div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
    <li ng-repeat="item in data.products">
        <img ng-src="assets/img/{{item.imgSRC}}" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

want to pull my data.products but cant seem to get it to work

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059492/angularjs-only-shows-last-element-in-ng-repeat/24067352 they are showing multiple flex sliders, but the markup in the template should assist you getting started. Also if you'd like some more help, creating a plnkr or fiddle would be very helpful for those helping you.

Comment: Thanks for replying!! ive manged to create this but still cant seem get my scope to pull my current product list. ive update my answer

Comment: before <ul class="slides"> write {{data}} it should show list of products when you show your slider, if it dont, than your data object is empty which means you are not loading it correctly.

Comment: thanks everyone managed to get it sorted!! had item="array" inside my call on my main html page